# Unable to start gnome applications because of shared library libappstream

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, shared-library, garuda-linux

Whenever I am trying to start a gnome applications (like calculator, Files, event gnome-control-center), I get the following error:

```
gnome-control-center: error while loading shared libraries: libappstream.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After further research, It appeared that I don't have `libappstream.so.4` in `/usr/lib/`, yet I do not find online any way to install this specific version of appstream on arch.

Distribution: Garuda Linux 2.6.19-2
gnome-firmware version: 45.0-1

Comment: that sounds like you did a partial update of arch. Does doing a whole-system update solve the issue?

Comment: Doing a full system upgrade did not changed anything sadly

Comment: :( then I'm all out of ideas, because it's unlikely you installed any gnome core stuff via an AUR, so in theory the distro mechanisms should keep components compatible.

Comment: no problem, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error one week ago or something and for me this was because `appstream` had been updated to version `1.0.0-5` which was not compatible with `gnome-software`. My solution was to downgrade `appstream` the previous version (`0.16.4-1`). If you have it in your pacman cache the following command should do it:

```
sudo pacman -U file:///var/cache/pacman/pkg/appstream-0.16.4-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
```

If you don't have it in you cache you should be able to download it from here instead https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/a/appstream/appstream-0.16.4-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst and install.

You can then add `appstream` to `IgnorePkg` in `/etc/pacman.conf` to prevent it from being upgraded in the future if downgrading it fixed your issue, e.g.:

```
IgnorePkg = appstream
```

Read more about downgrading here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/downgrading_packages

Comment: The second part of your answer worked perfectly, thanks!